# Decrypt data when loaded from mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, encryption

This is driving me nuts!

I have a small program getting data from a mysql database.
There are two columns in the table *tbl_credent* that contain encrypted data, called  *U_Password* and *U_SecQu*.

I want the data to be decrypted when loaded into my Dataset.

Here is the function that loads the data as it is:

```
    private void setBindSource()
    {
        string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM myDatabase.tbl_credent;";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdString, _connection);
        //_connection is globally defined 
        ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        _BindSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
        _BindSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

I have a function that decrypts data:

```
public string decryptData(string encryptedData, string password)
```

this is working fine, but I don't now how to use this with the function above.

Comment: could you subclass your data adapter and override `Fill`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decrypt every string one by one:

Put this code just after `da.Fill(ds);`

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    row["U_Password"] = decryptData(row["U_Password"] as string, "password");
    row["U_SecQu"] = decryptData(row["U_SecQu"] as string, "password");
}
```